# How do I add a second namespace to a SOAP envelope tag?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to create a SOAP message using PHP's DOMDocument class. I have a raw XML example to work from, and need to start off with an envelope that matches the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://example.url/v1">
```

To create this, I have been trying:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$env = $xml->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope', 'soapenv:Envelope');
$env->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns', 'xmlns:v1', 'http://example.url/v1');
```

At this point (using the PHP console), I get an uncaught DOMException with the message "Namespace Error".

I'm very new to crafting SOAP requests by hand, so I've no doubt I'm misunderstanding something basic. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, with a wonderfully simply answer.

Turns out that http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/ **requires** that trailing slash.